# SWRevealViewController insertObject:atIndex object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu, xcode6, swrevealviewcontroller

i'm a new developper with storyboard.i try to make a app with a slide-out menu.
To do this, i use the library : SWRevealViewController and the tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/ .

i follow the tutorial, but i load the application, i'have this error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

my app crash on this line :

```
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

how can i set self.revealViewController ?

here my storyboard **UPDATED**:

[image]

to understand my app, startviewController is used to download and store data, after downloading, the mainViewcontroller is showed.

i want my slide out menu on my mainviewcontroller, but i cant not do.

here the code i add to my mainviewController viewdidload :

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
         self.contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        _sharedUser = [User sharedUser];

        ///slide out menu
        // Change button color
         //SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RevealViewController"];


        _sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

        // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
        _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
        _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

        // Set the gesture
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];



        //end slide out



        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];


        if (_sharedUser.tokenString) {

        }
        else{

            [self showHomeWithoutLogginView];

        }



    }
```

Comment: where the code for prepareForSegue method ? Cross check with the tutorial after relaxing your mind as that tutorial is correct :)

Comment: Add line of code for your tableView data source. Some NSMutable array in your code trying to add object wich is nil.

Comment: before the part "Adding the Menu Items in Navigation Menu" nothing in tutorial speak about prepareForSegue method, can tell me what a i need to write and where ?

@Mayo323 the error is coming from self.revealViewController who is nil. My tableView can be show without data.

Comment: Did you complete whole tutorial or just part of it?

Comment: i didn't complete it, i stopped juste before "Adding the Menu Items in Navigation Menu". but it should work in theory no ?

Comment: Maybe somewhere after that is something to be need for program to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at the tutorial you are following. According to your screenshot, there are some stuff missing in your storyboard.

The RevealViewController should be connected with two controllers: a front viewController (for displaying content) and a rear viewController (for showing the navigation menu):

[image]

Credits for the image: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Those connections (segues) should be marked as "reveal view controller" and each of them have to be named accordingly: "sw_front" and "sw_rear".

Then you have to add the menu items in the navigation menu (rear view controller) and connect each cell to the corresponding viewController, give the segues a name and mark them as a SWRevealViewController class. You may want to connect the front view controller to the viewController you want to be shown first.

I strongly suggest you make the tutorial as it is. I think I used it in the past and it worked pretty well. If you have any doubt about it don't hesitate to ask.

Best of lucks!

Comment: i just updated my storyboard are right now. but the error continue.
the difference between me and the tutorial is, in the tutorial the initial controller is SWRevealViewController and in my case that's not the same. 
my app crash on this line :
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

how can i set self.revealViewController ?

Comment: You just have to `#import "SWRevealViewController.h"` whenever you want to call `self.revealViewController`. 
I'm looking at your updated storyboard. You didn't connect the cells of your menu with the views they have to display after tapping them. You need to connect each cell with a view and select "reveal view controller" as the segue.

Comment: before to show some view, i want to see the menu !
i try this : 

 'if ( self.revealViewController )
    {
        [_sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
        [_sidebarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
        [self.revealViewController panGestureRecognizer];
   }'

but app dont go in the condition, and then when i push on the button to show the slide out menu, nothing appens .....

Comment: Can you update your question and put your sideBar code and the code of a viewController from where you are able so display the sideBar?

Comment: It will be perfect if you upload your project.

Comment: Why do you have a code in MainViewController when the user taps the button? You don't have to implement `revealToggle:`. It's a SWRevealViewController method.

Comment: You should delete all that if-block listed in your "UPDATE 2".

Comment: i just follow the tutorial ^^
here my project :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lthiwrv42n07gwl/FoodStash.zip?dl=0

thanks in advance :)

Comment: i deleted the block, but now nothing appens when i click on the "item" button.

Comment: Your code was really messed up, hehe. Here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wx2x193v9c6ilrd/FoodStash-fixed.zip?dl=0. Two main issues: in StartViewController you had to call SWRevealViewController (not MainViewController because SW... contains all the architecture); and you had to implement the UITableView delegates in SideMenuViewController. I fixed the issues with SW...; there're more issues waiting for you ;). When working with new stuff I suggest you to make the tutorials outside your project so you can understand it deeply. Also I suggest you to make a tutorial on UITableViewController.

Comment: thanks a lot !!!! I'm not very good programmers ;(
my issue was solved just with this stuff from you :
'SWRevealViewController *sideBar = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController"];
        
        
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:sideBar animated:YES]; '

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**
thanks to leandro !

here the code who is need in my staviewcontroller who solved my problem:

```
 SWRevealViewController *sideBar = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController"];


 [self.navigationController pushViewController:sideBar animated:YES];
```

Comment: Is this full code ? please write full code solve your problem

Comment: yes this is full code, if you follow the SWRevealViewController tutorial, with storyboard connection, you just need this before displaying the sideBarController.
the sideBarController will display your main Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [latest version](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) of the SWRevealViewController? The AppCoda tutorial is outdated, and SWReveal has great sample on Git.

Check your segue **identifier** and **class** on your storyboard. Have you set sw_front and sw_rear? Also, in the latest version, your segue for setting the Menu / Front View should be: `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController` and not the old `SWRevealViewControllerSegue`.

**EDIT:**

Also note that calling `[self.revealController panGestureRecognizer];` is enough to enable the gesture; no need for an additional gesture.

**EDIT:**

Try initializing like this:

```
MenuViewController *menuVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];

UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainNavigationController"];

SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:menuVC frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
```

**EDIT:**

Can you try adding an action to your Menu Button like this:

```
[menuButton addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: yes i use the latest one ;)
i haved set sw_front and sw_rear and my segue are : SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController
the difference between me and the tutorial is than i use a startviewcontroller and the my initial viewcontroller is not the SWRevealViewController.suddenly when i try to use SWRevealViewController , it's nil....

i try to initialize like that :
   `SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController"];`

but when i'm clicking on the button to show the slide menu, my app crash with exec bad access ..

Comment: thanks for the anskwer, but when i'm clicking on the button to show the slide menu, my app crash with exec bad access and i dont know why :(